# How to dataset after ajax communication with vuejs

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm trying to implement modal windows with Vuejs.
The code below shows that after the user uploads the favorite photo,
then modal window appears, and photos which were uploaded so far and the newly registered photos are displayed
it will confirm when the user press the "confirm" button.

However, at present, data is not set in the modal window after fetching data with ajax after uploading.
How do I set the data in the modal window part?

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- upload -->
    <div class="button__action">
        <button type="button" @click="uploadData(originalData.image)">upload</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal window -->
    <modal name="modal-view">
        <div>
            <div class="modal__box" v-if="modalList.list">
                <img :src="modalList.list.url">
                <p class="image__name">{{modalList.list.name}}</p>
            </div>

            <button type="button" @click="submit">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </modal>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { post } from './handler/api'
import { toFormat } from './handler/form'

export default {
    props: {
        originalData: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        }
    },
    data: function(){
        return {
            modalList : {
                list : [],
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showModal () {
            this.$modal.show('modal-view');
        },
        uploadData() {
            const form = toFormat({image: this.originalData.image})
            post(`/api/upload/`, form)
                .then((res) => {
                    if(res.data) {
                        Vue.set(this.$data, 'modalList', res.data.list);
                        this.$modal.show('modal-view');
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    //error
                })
        },
        submit() {

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to set the `list` property of `modalList` instead of setting `modalList` itself?

Comment: Sorry, mistake. I wanted to set 'list' property. You're right!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
uploadData() {
  var vm = this;
  post(`/api/upload/`, toFormat({image: this.originalData.image})).then(res => {
    if(res.data) {
      vm.modalList = res.data.list;
      this.$modal.show('modal-view');
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: thaks! It works fine!! but I do not know why...what do you put vm for?

Comment: the name vm is a shortcut for viewModel and it is all about scope. Inside the  'then' function the 'this' is not the same as the one from outside. So I've saved the scope (your view model/ outside 'this') inside the 'vm' variable and now you can acces your modalList. BTW if it works could you accept the answer? :) thank you!